# spinner cannot be applied to (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.onitemselectedlistener)

Tags: android

i have to select items from spinner. Actually i am making gpa calculator.I have given grades in spinner and person can select from that. I have to assign grades with like A will 4, B+ will be 3.5 and so on. That's why i have to extract value after user has selected from spinner. But i am getting that spinner cannot be applied to adapter view.

setonitemclicklistener (android.widget.AdapterView.onitemclicklistener)   in spinner cannot be applied to  (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.onitemselectedlistener)

Comment: show the code where it appears

Comment: add your code snippet in your question

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "position: " + position);
        }
    });
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setOnItemSelectedListener`to do something on an item selected like below:

```
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //  Do Something
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: sam if i had to shift from main activity to the name of activities given in spinner, should i use "i" variable for getting their position and make intent of each activities in switch?

Comment: @NaveedMalik Yes Naveed, `i` represents the position of the view in the adapter. You can also rename it from `i` to `position`. You can look into [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) to know more about  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.

Comment: @NaveedMalik I've altered the answer as well for a better understanding.